# Cisco 5505 VPN RDP not working

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa

I am in dire straights over here. We just changed our LAN from a 192.168.1.0 to a 172.16.4.0.
We run Active Directory in our environment and our gateway is a Cisco 5505 ASA.
Since the change, our clients can VPN in and make a connection but cannot RDP to any machines that they need to get to on the LAN that they VPN into. I updated the VPN address pool and DNS servers but I'm not sure what else I need to configure. I can send anything you need as I am not an expert and I really, really appreciate the help!

Comment: Can you provide some of the configuration details from the device?  I'd suspect that there's something wrong with NAT exemptions or maybe a split tunnel ACL.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not familiar with asa too, but you could take a look at ACL's part, from your description it looks like you didn't updated them. `show access-list` will show your acl's. also, you can take a look at whole config by running this command `show running-config`, maybe you will see some old ip's there.